# Handler. Сбиваются задержки (продолжительность пауз) в Handler'е (обработчике)

Tags: android, android-handler

Первый раз когда вот этот код выполняется, то все работает нормально! С задержками (паузами) в 1 секунду выдаются сообщения в TextView!

Но когда этот же кусок вызывается в последующие разы, то все показывается нормально, НО задержки (паузы) сбиваются, и становятся разными по продолжительности: примерно от 0 до 1 секунды.

```
private Handler mHandler;  
boolean gameOn; 
int i; 
String st;

...
...
...

st=""; i=0;
mHandler = new Handler(){
  public void handleMessage(Message msg){
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    if (gameOn) {
      st += mas_id[i] + " ";
      tvShow.setText( st );
      i++;
      if (mas_id[i]==0||i>99) gameOn = false;
    }
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
  }
};
gameOn = true;
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что каждый раз создаётся новый `Handler` и его сообщения накладываются на предыдущие. Создавать `Handler` нужно только один раз и перед отправкой в него нового сообщения - очищать от предыдущих:

```
if (mHandler != null) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, тебе, друг!!!